# How to manually install and uninstall Rust?

Tags: rust

I'd like to try on a "hello world" program on Rust. I didn't choose *rustup* for auto-installation but downloaded the [standalone installer](https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/rust-1.56.1-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.gz). I thought I could follow the classic way to manually install it on Linux platform bundled with GCC and Clang below,

```
$ tar xf rust-xxx.tar.gz; mv rust-xxx $RUST_HOME 
$ cd /usr/local/bin; sudo ln -s $RUST_HOME/bin/rustc
$ rustc hello.rs; ./hello
```

However I found *install.sh* inside, so I have to run it for the installation, don't I? How to completely uninstall it afterwards?

Comment: I'd recommend https://play.rust-lang.org/ for quick-and-dirty messing around with Rust.

Comment: Long while ago i messed around a little bit. Now the ecosys grows and the rustup steps in, which are obviously welcome. Unfortunately I forget how i had installed and uninstalled manually in the past.

Comment: If you want to install software in a way that won't impact the rest of your system in any way (except when you actively want that software to be in your current environment), might I suggest [Nix](https://nixos.org)? Mozilla actively maintains a set of Rust derivations for it if you want things to be bleeding-edge, whereas the default package set has a perfectly workable set of Rust packages as well. Everything you install with Nix lives in its own hash-addressed directory tree and only ends up in your PATH when you want it there.

Answer (score 2):

I just downloaded the archive you linked and had a look inside the installation script.

During installation it will create an `uninstall.sh` script and actually print out for you the location:

```sh
install_uninstaller() {
    local _src_dir="$1"
    local _src_basename="$2"
    local _abs_libdir="$3"

    local _uninstaller="$_abs_libdir/$TEMPLATE_REL_MANIFEST_DIR/uninstall.sh"
    msg "creating uninstall script at $_uninstaller"
    run cp "$_src_dir/$_src_basename" "$_uninstaller"
    critical_need_ok "unable to install uninstaller"
}

#...


# Install the uninstaller
install_uninstaller "$src_dir" "$src_basename" "$abs_libdir"
```